# Nginx rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting

Tags: redirect, nginx

I am having troubles with nginx.

Here is my config.

```
server {
    listen                  80;
    listen                  [::]:80;
    server_name             www.test.local;
    return                  301 http://test.local$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name             test.local;
    root                    /usr/share/nginx/test/htdocs/web;

    # error_log               /var/log/nginx/test.error.log;
    # access_log              /var/log/nginx/test.access.log;

    rewrite                 ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

    location / {
        index app.php;
        try_files           $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$      /app.php/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass        172.17.0.1:48000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;

        include             fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param       SCRIPT_FILENAME  $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param       DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }

    location /uploads/ {
        root                /usr/share/nginx/test/htdocs/web/uploads;
        try_files           $uri $uri/;
        access_log          off;
        expires             30d;
    }

    location /images/ {
        root                /usr/share/nginx/test/htdocs/web/images;
        try_files           $uri $uri/;
        access_log          off;
        expires             30d;
    }

    location /css/ {
        root                /usr/share/nginx/test/htdocs/web/css;
        try_files           $uri $uri/;
        access_log          off;
        expires             30d;
    }

    location /js/ {
        root                /usr/share/nginx/test/htdocs/web/js;
        try_files           $uri $uri/;
        access_log          off;
        expires             30d;
    }

    location /fonts/ {
        root                /usr/share/nginx/test/htdocs/web/fonts;
        try_files           $uri $uri/;
        access_log          off;
        expires             30d;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        return              204;
        access_log          off;
        log_not_found       off;
    }
}
```

I want my locations as http://test.local/css/ link to /usr/share/nginx/test/htdocs/styles/ as i did it in my config.

But when im entering for example http://test.local/css/flow.css im getting next error:

```
2016/05/13 15:55:30 [error] 5#5: *64 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/css/flow.css///////////", client: 192.168.99.1, server: test.local, request: "GET /css/flow.css HTTP/1.1", host: "test.local", referrer: "http://test.local/"
```

Whats the problem here?

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems with your configuration.

The first problem is that your `root` directives are wrong, so the file is not found.

The second problem is that the default action is to add another `/` to the end of the URI.

You need to add a valid default action to your `try_files` directive, such as a 404 response:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

So, back to the first problem. Your configuration states that `/css/example.css` is located at `/usr/share/nginx/test/htdocs/web/css/css/example.css`. Notice that `/css/` is replicated. Same goes for `/images/`, `/js/` and `/fonts/`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details of the `root` directive.

In most configurations, it is sufficient to specify the `root` at the `server` block level and allow it to be inherited by almost all `location` blocks, rather than repeating it in each location.

Your question states that `/css/` files should be found in `/usr/share/nginx/test/htdocs/styles/`. This requires an `alias` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details of the `alias` directive. For example:

```
location /css/ {
    alias       /usr/share/nginx/test/htdocs/styles/;
    access_log  off;
    expires     30d;
}
```